# how to use postgresql in Java

Tags: java, postgresql

I Installed postgresql and its driver which is "postgresql-9.3-1102.jdbc41.jar".

And my directory seems like :

```
> SQL
>     myJDBC.java
>     postgresql-9.3-1102.jdbc41.jar
```

I have tried :

```
javac -cp postgresql-9.3-1102.jdbc41.jar myJDBC.java
java -cp postgresql-9.3-1102.jdbc41.jar myJDBC
```

It compiles fine but when I try to execute it, I get error which is :

```
Error: Could not find or load main class myJDBC
```

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current directory needs to be added to the runtime classpath

```
java -cp .:postgresql-9.3-1102.jdbc41.jar myJDBC
         ^
```

Comment: When I do that I get : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgreql.Driver
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
 at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
 at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:191)

Comment: There ought to be a letter 's' in org.postgreql.Driver, check your code

Comment: Sorry, my edit and comment had become obsolete in light of your `ClassNotFoundException`.

Comment: @okiharaherbst I'm truly sorry I'm kind of newbie I didn't get it what do you mean, The Jar file and myJDBC in same directory already ? how can use fully qualified package name ?

Comment: @VivianMaya change `org.postgreql.Driver` `->` `org.postgresql.Driver` (postgre*S*ql) in your code. And try again.

Comment: @okiharaherbst I fixed as reimeus answer,and I got error which are shared on first my comment ?

Comment: @VivianMaya Okay. Now prefix `MyJDBC` with the fully qualified package name, eg.: `com.example.subpackage.MyJDBC`. If it still doesn't work, then please edit your question and post the relevant portions of your code.

Comment: @okiharaherbst oh my god, I get it now what a mistake,I'm grateful,thank you for your attention...

Comment: Looks like the lesson to learn is never type a package name. Either copy-paste or use an IDE that provides a type-ahead feature to auto-suggest the parts of the package name. (See Intellij, NetBeans, Eclipse, JDeveloper.)

Comment: I'm using vim but I create a dictionary for these stuff at the end :) .

Comment: @BasilBourque I don't know, but I like vim and wouldn't trade it for Eclipse. Imo, string literals such as JDBC driver name, URI, user/pass credentials and queries are best passed as arguments anyway instead of having them compiled (just my 2¢).