# JDBC driver issue on compiling java program from terminal

Tags: java, eclipse, postgresql, jdbc, driver

I went through a lot of questions like  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26805821/how-to-use-postgresql-in-java/%22this%22)  and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18142711/postgres-no-suitable-driver-found-for-jdbc/%22this%22) which were almost same as mine ,but couldn't help me in solving my problem. I am hence posting it for help.
I was trying to use the JDBC driver with PostgreSQL and followed [this tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/how-do-connect-to-postgresql-with-jdbc-driver-java/). 
I tried the same Java program on Eclipse as well as trying to compile from the terminal. After putting the **postgresql-9.4-1206-jdbc4.jar** in the library folder in Eclipse, it compiles and runs **perfectly** in the IDE.
Now I have put my JDBCExample.java and postgresql-9.4-1206-jdbc4.jar in the same folder **test**.
But when I try in my terminal with this,

```
cd test
javac JDBCExample.java
java JDBCExample -cp postgresql-9.4-1206-jdbc4.jar
```

I get

```
-------- PostgreSQL JDBC Connection Testing ------------
Where is your PostgreSQL JDBC Driver? Include in your library path!
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.Driver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:191)
    at JDBCExample.main(JDBCExample.java:14)
```

I also tried rewriting the second command as `java JDBCExample -cp .:postgresql-9.4-1206-jdbc4.jar`  but there is no change. 
What is wrong here?

Comment: reverse the order, `-cp ...` before `JDBCExample`; you are currently passing the parameters `-cp` and `postgresql-9.4-1206-jdbc4.jar` to your application instead of to Java.

Comment: When I do that `java -cp postgresql-9.4-1206-jdbc4.jar  JDBCExample` , I am getting `Could not find or load main class JDBCExample` error.

Comment: @zorro_blue Because the `-cp` option replaces the classpath, so you also have to specify where to find `JDBCExample.class`, e.g. `-cp .;postgresql-9.4-1206-jdbc4.jar` to include the local directory.

Comment: @Andreas Like this  `java -cp .;postgresql-9.4-1206-jdbc4.jar  ~/test/JDBCExample` ? That gives me a command not found error :(

Comment: @zorro_blue: Replace the semicolon with a colon if you are not under Windows.

Comment: @Chriki It worked!! Thanks !! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, setting up the call to be

```
java -cp .:postgresql-9.4-1206-jdbc4.jar ~/test/JDBCExample
```

worked.